# Interaction with Lists in SPFx

Tags: list, spfx, spfx-webparts

Are there any tutorials which are better than the Microsoft Tutorial for explaining integrating with lists? I've found the one provided by MS to be outdated and skips actually doing anything with lists.

Comment: Could you specify which tutorial you have issue with and what interaction you are looking for?

Comment: I was trying to use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/tutorial-share-data-between-web-parts-global-variable to try and figure out how interacting with lists works.